# My most recent commit works. My current working set has a bug. How do I find out what change caused the bug?

Tags: git

A change I've made since the latest commit has introduced a bug. I've read through the diff (between the latest commit and my presently uncommitted working set) a thousand times, and can't for my life figure out what change has introduced this bug. How can I use git to find out which change caused the bug to appear?

Comment: Ask someone else to read your code. Add logging code. As for git, create a branch and commit all the changes, and then reset partially hunk by hunk to find out which hunk introduces the bug.

Comment: `git checkout --patch` not reset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`git` cannot help you here, since you just have a big (?) heap of changes that aren't even committed. You could however (ab)use `git` to help you find the mistake:

Commit your changes in small commits that are functional (probably you'll already find your problem when doing this). I'd recommend using `git add -p` to stage only part of your developments, something like:

```
git add -p
# select some minor changes that make up one small working commit
git commit -m "first working changes"
git stash # move all other changes aside in a git stash
# now test if your code still works, if it does, you can continue:
git stash pop # put the stashed changes back
# repeat the previous actions.
```

This will help you commit your working changes bit by bit.

Supposing you had made many small commits, you could have used `git bisect` to help you find the faulty commit.

Answer (score 2):

You can't find it with git since git doesn't know the behavior of your code, it only keeps versions of it.

You can comment out or stash some parts of your work to find the bug.

For the next time, if the diff is to big you can try to commit more often smaller piece of code so you can revert your commits easily to find a bug

Comment: Git *can* help find issues like these if they are between commits using git bisect. So it's not that git can't help with the task, it's just that the fact that the problem ocured in a single commit means that git won't help in *this case*.